# Jquery Copy input field to another input outside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some jquery I have been working to debug. I have a search field that when I enter the text into the input field at the top of the page, I am expecting the value of the first input to be copied directly over to the #search_visibleTest input. The code works perfectly when I have the two inputs together.

My Issue:
When I enter the text in the first search input in its own div, the input with the correct id of the secondary field is not working or populating. Any insights on what I am doing wrong. Let me know if you need more information.

```
<div class="head">
    <input class="form-input" id="search_visible" name="search_visible" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off">
</div>

<div class="body">
    <form>
        <input class="form-input" id="search_visibleTest" name="search_visible" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off">
    </form>
</div>

<script>
  $("#search_visible").keyup(function(){
      $("#search_visibleTest").val(this.value);
  });
</script>
```

The script does work with the code below only. I am not sure what the issue is. I am not getting any console errors.

```
<div class="head">
    <input class="form-input" id="search_visible" name="search_visible" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off">
    <input class="form-input" id="search_visibleTest" name="search_visible" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this. This will mirror any change on an input with the data-mirror attribute to any other input with data-mirror. Then you can bind as many as you like.

```js
$('[data-mirror]').on('change keyup paste',function(){
  $('[data-mirror]').val(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-mirror><br/>
<input type="text" data-mirror><br/>
<div>
  <input type="text" data-mirror>
</div>
```