# How to display date from input to another input with javascript?

Tags: javascript, input, datepicker

> my concept is to type something in one input and at the same time that
>   value will print in another field. all fields are working except date.
>   I am using bootstrap datepicker to display date. I am helpless to
>   display date on another field. please help me with the same. Below is
>   my code to display normal text and date too.

```
<div class="control-group">             
     <label class="control-label">Address:</label>
     <div class="controls">
        <input required type="text" id="c7"  class="span2 insert">      
     </div>
</div>
```

**id c7 is using to display text in below** `span`

`Address:<span class="rc7"></span>`

**script for this:**

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var id=$(this).attr('id');
    //alert(id);
    var na=$('#'+id).val();
    $('.r'+id).text(na);        
    //alert(id+na);
});
```

**date html code**

```
<div class="control-group">                 
<label class="control-label">Date:</label>
<div class="controls input-group date">
    <input type="text" class="span2 insert angular_input" id="c8"><span class="input-group-addon " style="display:none;"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

> same script im using for date too as above.
>
> if i type something in address input it will display in span. same i
>   want in date

Comment: Check the similar kind of question and responses from team: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42959673/7564893

Answer (score 0):

Try change event like this

```
   $('input').change(function(e){
           // set value in other input 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="control-group">                 
<label class="control-label">Date:</label>
<div class="controls input-group date">
    <input type="text" class="span2 insert angular_input" id="c8">
      <span class="input-group-addon " id = "rc8" style="display:none;">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
      </span>
</div>

<script>
   var inputField = document.querySelector("#c8");
   inputField.addEventListener("input",function(){
     var span = document.querySelector("#rc8");
     span.style.display = "block";
     span.textContent = inputField.value;
   })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change event like this

```
$('input').change(function(e){
    $("span").text(e.target.value);
});
```